# Equivalent in Java of a Fortran 2D CHARACTER*8 array

Tags: java, arrays, string, fortran

I'm currently "translating" a program from FORTRAN to JAVA, and I have some lines declaring variables like this :

```
CHARACTER *8 INDICATIF_BUT(NPTBUTS,NBPDV)
```

and I would like to know how to translate it in java code.

I thought about making a 3D array, like this :

```
char[][][] INDICATIF_BUT = new char[8][NPTBUTS][NBPDV];
```

But I'm not sure it is the right way to do it.

NB : I would like to stick with the char thing, and not using String, to be the closest possible to the original code.

Comment: It looks OK to me. The only things is that I think that you have to reverse the order of the dimensions to get similar ordering in memory. char[][][] INDICATIF_BUT = new char[NBPDV][NPTBUTS][8];

Comment: @innoSPG okay thanks, I will try that ;)

Comment: Depending on how the Fortran strings were originally used, migrating to Java Strings instead of character arrays may be a better solution. I understand the desire to stay close to the original implementation but Fortran text handling has always been pretty miserable and it can be even more painful to port. Provided you understand the intent of the original code, it may be much easier to reimplement the current facilities using modern constructs (regexs, variable length strings, etc.)

Comment: @arclight yeah I know, but later in the code I have to manipulate characters precisely to write binary data in a file, so I think I will continue to use the character way. But the .toCharArray String function is really convenient though... ^^

Comment: @innoSPG It worked perfectly, thank you :)